# Не срабатывает ассоциативность умножения матриц в случае QTransform

Tags: c++, qt

Есть в наличии код формирования сцены для Qt OpenGL. Матрицы преобразования координат текстур - [`QTransform`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#details), вертексов [`QMatrix4x4`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#details). Пример рабочего кода:

```
QTransform textureBase, textureLocal;
QMatrix4x4 vertexBase, vertexLocal;
QVector<QVector3D> textureScene, vertexScene;
...
for(const QVector3D &point: texturePoints)
    textureScene << textureBase * (textureLocal * point);

for(const QVector3D &point: vertexPoints)
    vertexScene << vertexBase * (vertexLocal * point);
```

Тут есть проблема, что точка умножается на две матрицы. Хотелось бы перемножить матрицы заранее и с `QMatrix4x4` всё как и положено `vertexBase * (vertexLocal * point) == (vertexBase * vertexLocal) * point` [ассоциативность умножения матриц](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86) в действии.

А вот для `QTransform` так не получается: `textureBase * (textureLocal * point) != (textureBase * textureLocal) * point`. Почему так происходит, ведь по описанию они обе - матрицы? И как это исправить?

*Уточняю по просьбе @Andrej-Levkovitch. Сравнивал в отладчике. Отличается сильно - в разы, то есть не из-за погрешности операций с плавающей точкой.*

Вот тестовые примеры:

```
QTransform a(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
QTransform b(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);
QMatrix4x4 ma(a);
QMatrix4x4 mb(b);
auto p1 = a.map(b.map(QPointF(1, 0)));
auto p1_ = (a * b).map(QPointF(1, 0));
auto p1__ = (b * a).map(QPointF(1, 0));
auto p2 = a * (b * QVector3D(1, 0, 0));
auto p2_ = (a * b) * QVector3D(1, 0, 0);
auto p3 = ma * (mb * QVector3D(1, 0, 0));
auto p3_ = (ma * mb) * QVector3D(1, 0, 0);
```

В результате координата `x` равна 2 и `y` равна 2 у всех `p` кроме `p1_` и `p2_`, у которых `x` равна 1, а `y` равна 3. То есть `p1_ == p2_` и не равна прочим `p`. В том числе `p1__ == p1 == p3...`

Comment: а как вы сравнивали?

Comment: поэлементно. `textureBase * (textureLocal * point)` - это QVector3D - просто x,y,z. Собственно, точка `textureBase * (textureLocal * point)` не равна точке `(textureBase * textureLocal) * point`

Answer (score 0):

Вангую: вы сравнивали два случая прямо через оператор `!=`  котороый определен в классе [QMatrix4x4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#operator-not-eq). Но, как и сказано в документации, он сравнивает матрицы на идентичность - не забывайте, что числа с плавающей точкей нельзя сравнивать через `==` или `!=` для случаев когда аргументы были вычеслены

Comment: Нет. Я сравнивал в дебаге, просматривая элементы списков векторов. Предположу, что вас смутило `!=` в вопросе. Просто поленился написать "не равно" :)

Comment: @mrNAE все ещё не понятно как вы сравнивали: на глаз? Сильно значения отличались?

Comment: @mrNAE уточните это в вопросе - поможет другим понять проблему

Comment: @mrNAE уточните это в вопросе - поможет другим понять проблему

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы - преобразовать явно `QTransform` в `QMatrix4x4`:

```
...
QMatrix4x4(textureBase)* QMatrix4x4(textureLocal) * point;
...
```

В таком варианте ассоциативность выполняется.

Почему такое возникает?

`QTransform` не имеет оператора умножения на `QVector3D`. А у `QMatrix4x4` он есть, что логично, а так же есть оператор преобразования типа из `QTransform`. Поэтому, корректно работает `textureBase * (textureLocal * point)` так как оно разворачивается в следующую последовательность:

```
QVector3D result1 = textureBase * (textureLocal * point);
// эквивалентно:
QMatrix4x4 tmp1(textureLocal);
QVector3D tmp2 = tmp1 * point;
QMatrix4x4 tmp3(textureBase);
QVector3D result1 = tmp3 * point;
```

А если применить ожидаемую ассоциативность:

```
QVector3D result2 = (textureBase * textureLocal) * point;
// эквивалентно:
QTransform tmp4 = textureBase * textureLocal;
QMatrix4x4 tmp5(tmp1);
QVector3D result2 = tmp5 * point;
```

то результат будет некорректным: `result1` отличается от `result2` значительно (кроме частных случаев, естественно). И это не из-за каких-то ошибок вычисления или преобразований.

А дело тут вот в чём. Не вдаваясь в детали реализации, `QMatrix4x4` транспонирует аффинную часть `QTransform` при перекладывании элементов матриц. *На самом деле это не совсем так, чуть сложнее, но сути не меняет*.

Пусть `A` `B` это матрицы `QTransform` тогда `textureBase * (textureLocal * point)` выглядит так:

**A**<sup>T</sup> * (**B**<sup>T</sup> * point) = **A**<sup>T</sup> * **B**<sup>T</sup> * point

а `(textureBase * textureLocal) * point` так:

(**A** * **B**)<sup>T</sup> * point = **B**<sup>T</sup> * **A**<sup>T</sup> * point

**A**<sup>T</sup> * **B**<sup>T</sup> != **A**<sup>T</sup> * **B**<sup>T</sup>